# Store enum collection in database using ORMLite

Tags: java, database, enums, ormlite

I'm trying to save enum collection in database with ORMLite. So while creating Dao I'm getting no-args constructor error

I have tried create default package contructor, but it doesn't helps - I think ORMLite requires public constructor, but enums cannot have it.

My enum looks like this (separated .java file)

```java
enum RankPermission {
  @DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.ENUM_TO_STRING)
  ALL,
  //...
  ;

  RankPermission() {}
}
```

And collection in another class is

```java
@DatabaseTable
class Rank {
  @ForeignCollectionField
  Collection<RankPermission> permissions;

  public Rank() {}
}
```

Dao creation and error which I have got

```java
DaoManager.createDao(conn, Rank.class);
```

```java
        [23:31:12 ERROR]: Can't find a no-arg constructor for class package.core.rank.RankPermission
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a no-arg constructor for class package.core.rank.RankPermission
        at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.findNoArgConstructor(DatabaseTableConfig.java:229) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.getConstructor(DatabaseTableConfig.java:154) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableInfo.<init>(TableInfo.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableInfo.<init>(TableInfo.java:54) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:156) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:112) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:1044) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:1044) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:70) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:392) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:206) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:112) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:1044) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:1044) ~[?:?]
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:70) ~[?:?]
        at package.storage.yaml.db.DatabaseConnector.initDaos(DatabaseConnector.java:152) ~[?:?]
```

I would like to save this collection in enum form, beacause it is more comfortable

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I've just used any Collection from `java.util` package and set `@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE)` annotation instead of `@ForeignCollectionField` to save serialized data, so now code is

```java
class Rank {
    @DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    private HashSet<RankPermission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

It's important to set `HashSet` type to field, because ORMLite will not detect serializable interface on `Set`.